# svg storke-dashoffest makes anti clockwise animation

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

I tried to draw a svg circle. As i need to animate it using stroke-dashoffest the circle's stroke fills only in anti-clockwise direction. Is there any way to move the animation in clock wise direction.

```
My Code:

 <svg width="130" height="130" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ -->


 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <g>
  <path stroke="blue" id="svg_1" d="m66.75,11.75a54,52 0 1 0 0.00001,0l-0.00001,0z" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="5" stroke-dashoffset="2000" stroke-dasharray="2000" fill="red">
    <animate id="project_study_anim1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="2000" to="0" begin="1s" dur="5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
  </path>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Maybe change `from="2000" to="0"` to `from="0" to="2000"`

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: thanks,but it take time to fill need to animate after the page loads

Comment: What you really should do is to change path start/stop, and reverse the path direction `m66.75,11.75a54,52 0 1 0 0.00001,0l-0.00001,0z`

Comment: can you help me with a sample code

Comment: If my skills with those SVG's would be good enough, I would, and also posted it as an answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142472/discussion-between-ram-and-lgson).

Comment: I got curious :) ... and read up a little and posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just flip the svg. [edit] you can use the inline transform to flip just the path:

```html
<svg id="this_svg" width="130" height="130" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <title>Layer 1</title>
    <g>
    <path transform= "translate(130),scale(-1,1)" stroke="blue" id="svg_1" d="m66.75,11.75a54,52 0 1 0 0.00001,0l-0.00001,0z" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="5" stroke-dashoffset="2000" stroke-dasharray="2000" fill="red">
      <animate id="project_study_anim1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="2000" to="0" begin="1s" dur="5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1">     
      </animate>
    </path>
    </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: what happens if i need to have a content at the center of my circle

Comment: flip it over too :)

Comment: @Ram I've edit it to flip just the target path. Just translating and scaling it.

Comment: @ram in a svg file If you want to place a shape inside a another shape, you don't need to have **<path><path id="inside"></path><path>** but you will have **<path></path><path id="inside"></path>** using position property to position them. So if the 1st path has been flipped the 2nd doesn't.

Comment: Got it Bro. The explanation was like a spoon of honey. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain how the scale and transform works in the code above

Comment: scale transforms the target element size in this way **scale(x,y)**, wher **0 mean no size** and **1 mean original size**, a negative value like -1 filp the element on the axis where this value is placed. In this example we have x=-1 and y=1. In svg the scale property also move the element for a distance equal to its size. In this svg we have a width of 130, so scale(-1,1) move the element to -130 in the x axis. We need to move back it on the right position with the translate property, that move the element in this way translate(x,y). So we set x=130 to move back it.

Comment: There a lots of problems with this solution, as has been pointed out. Luckily there is a much simpler solution that involves changing one number.  See my answer.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau what's problem?

Comment: Well the main one is that it only works if you are able to flip your path. Ie. it is symmetrical.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau nothing strange, it has been wrote for this path.

Answer (score 6):

To reverse the direction of a dashoffset animation, you don't need to reverse the path.  All you generally need to do is reverse the direction that the dash offset values change.

Normally that means making the non-zero number negative.  So, in your example, your dash offset goes from `2000` to `0`.  Change it to go from `-2000` to `0`.

In fact for your circle, 2000 is way too large a value for your dash pattern.  For your circle shape, the circumference is actually around 333.

See below:

```html
<svg width="130" height="130" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <g>
  <path stroke="blue" id="svg_1" d="m66.75,11.75a54,52 0 1 0 0.00001,0l-0.00001,0z" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="5" stroke-dashoffset="-333" stroke-dasharray="333" fill="red">
    <animate id="project_study_anim1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="-333" to="0" begin="1s" dur="5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
  </path>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Of course, one value less to change than mine ... plus 1

Answer (score 0):

So I read up a little on SVG path, and especially the arc `a`.

An arc has the `large-arc-flag` and `sweep-flag` to control how it is drawn.

The one you use has the `1,0` arc but you should use the `1,1`, here done in below sample. Also the end point needed an adjustment, to `-0.00001,0`.

As the `a` is quite complicated to explain, here is two links with some reading:

- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html#arcs
- https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/

```html
<svg width="130" height="130" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <g>
  <path stroke="blue" id="svg_1" d="m66.75,11.75 a54,52 0 1 1 -0.00001,0z" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="5" stroke-dashoffset="2000" stroke-dasharray="2000" fill="red">
    <animate id="project_study_anim1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="2000" to="0" begin="1s" dur="5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
  </path>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is not a general solution. It only helps if the path consists of a single arc. :(

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Just curious, how is changing the direction of a dashoffset animation using a negative value more a general solution than picking the arc that from the start is drawn in the right direction?

Comment: It is a more general solution because it works for any path.  Reversing a single arc command may not be that hard, but reversing a more complicated path is not so easy.