# Fill SVG shape from one point to another point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, gsap

I want to fill SVG shape from top left to end point with animation. I have tried css and also fill using tweenmax but cannot fill shape from top left end to next end point.

```css
.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  max-width: 0;
  float: left;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    max-width: 0;
  }

  100% {
    max-width: 112px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="fadeIn"   x="0px" y="0px"
              width="112px" height="60.775px" viewBox="0 0 112 60.775" enable-background="new 0 0 112 60.775" xml:space="preserve" >
 <path   fill="blue" d="M103.371,0.899L112,4.315c0,0-5.034,55.018-63.82,56.457             c0,0-28.584,0.898-48.18-24.273c0,0,8.629-13.305,11.505-13.665c0,0,9.528,20.137,38.652,20.497c0,0,39.551,1.258,44.405-43.331
             L103.371,0.899z"/>
            </svg>
```

Comment: Here is a start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583759/svg-storke-dashoffest-makes-anti-clockwise-animation

Comment: What is the "top left" and what is the "end point" in your shape. It's not immediately obvious.  Perhaps you could add a picture that shows what you are after. Also why do you have the shape expanding in width?  Is the fill supposed to happen at the same time?